# Array doesn't populate first time

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array

supplypayment and supplyBrand arrays has no values for the  first time when this function is called

```
this.getSupply().subscribe (list => {
      let array = list.map(item =>{
        return {
          $key: item.key,
          ...item.payload.val()
        };
      });
      array.forEach(element => {
        this.supplypayment.push(element.payment);
        this.supplyBrand.push(element.BrandName);
      });

    }
```

supplyPayment and supplyBrand is used in the chart in the console the supplyPayment and supplyBrand is undefined or the initialised value. but when call the same graph componen for the second time it works properly!

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.BarChart = new Chart('barChart2', {

      type: 'bar',
    data: {
     labels:this.x,
     datasets: [{
         label: 'Payment',
         data  :  this.serv.supplypayment,
         backgroundColor: [
             'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
             'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
             'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
             'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
             'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
             'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
         ],
         borderColor: [
             'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
             'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
             'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
             'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
             'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
             'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
         ],
         borderWidth: 1
     }]
    }, 
    options: {
     title:{
         text:this.serv.supNamerep,
         display:true
     },
     scales: {
         yAxes: [{
             ticks: {
                 beginAtZero:true
             }
         }]
     }
    }
    });

    this.serv.supplypayment = [];
    this.serv.supplyBrand= []

  }
```

Comment: Show template it's probobly u need `*ngIf` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
this.getSupply().subscribe (list => {
      this.supplypayments = list.map(item =>{
        return {
          $key: item.key,
          payment:item.payment,
          brandName:item.BrandName
        };
      });
}
```

You should not need to loop it again

In your markup yout can access the values like:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let supplyPayment of supplypayments">
    {{supplyPayment.$key}} - {{supplyPayment.payment.something}} - {{supplyPayment.brandName}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i want to store it in an array to do chart

Comment: please help im new to angular

Comment: supplypayments is an array. You need to describe your problem better

Comment: Given more details sir. i dont want it in the html file i want it in an .ts file

Comment: The getSupply().subscribe might take some time to execute. So populate the chart after the list response have arrived. Move the code from ngOnInit to a method ex initChart. Then call that method inside getSupply().subscribe. If you still have problems you might need to keep this.BarChart = new Chart('... inside the ngOnInit and the populate the chart when the subscribe hits

Answer (score 0):

If `supplypayment` and `supplyBrand` are unitialized (so, undefined), then here's what happens. All your pushes after `getSupply` do nothing except throwing errors (because `undefined.push is not a function`). But at the end of the `ngOnInit` you have those two lines:

```
    this.serv.supplypayment = [];
    this.serv.supplyBrand= []
```

after which they are proper arrays.

You should

```
// initialize the arrays
supplypayment: number[] = []; // or is it string[], or any other type[]? 
supplyBrand: string[] = [];

//...

this.getSupply().subscribe(list => {
    const array = list.map(item => ({ ...item.payload.val() }); // you weren't using $key anyway

    this.supplypayment = array.map(item => item.payment);
    this.supplyBrand = array.map(item => item.BrandName);
}
```